# How to search for only one particular record in MySQL table using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm making an app where I'm trying to login a user with data that's stored in MySQL server.
The Problem I'm getting is that when I try to login with correct username and password, my code is actually checking every record in my 'adminData' table and showing me corresponding results for every record!
I'm attaching my code too please have a look!
So I want to ask how I can only search for one particular record and it'll revert me only for that particular record!
Please help me out.. :)

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String query = "SELECT username, password FROM adminData";
        String username = null;
        String password = null;
        ;
        try
        {
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            String fieldWarning = "*all field are mandatory!";

            String enteredUsername = usernameField.getText();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") String enteredPassword = passwordField.getText();

            usernameField.setCursor(null);
            fieldLabel.setText("");

            int userLen = enteredUsername.length();
            int passLen = enteredPassword.length();

            if (userLen != 0 && passLen != 0)
            {
                if (userLen <= 32 && passLen <= 32)
                {
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        username = rs.getString("username");
                        password = rs.getString("password");
                        if (enteredUsername.equals(username))
                        {
                            if (enteredPassword.contentEquals(password))
                            {
                                AdminDashboard frame = new AdminDashboard();
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                                frame.dispose();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Missmatch");
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid User");
                            passwordField.setText("");
                            usernameField.setText("");
                            usernameField.setCursor(null);

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Please enter a valid username or password! \n(Note: Only 32 char MAX)");
                    passwordField.setText("");
                    usernameField.setText("");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fieldLabel.setText(fieldWarning);
                usernameField.setCursor(null);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database Error: " + e1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the primary key in your table ?

Comment: primary is 'id' that's on auto increment and I've made 'username' attribute unique

Comment: String query = "SELECT username, password FROM adminData WHERE id = '" + id +"'";

Comment: username= rs.getString("username");
                                                        password= rs.getString("password"); get these fields out of the while loop.

Comment: Too many problems to give an answer.  For starters, please don't store your user passwords as clear text in your database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beacuse your query returns you the whole table. If you have a username, you can simply tweak your query to only return row containing details of that specific user, instead of all the users. 
So, just assign enteredUsername before query, and add username condition to your sql query.

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String enteredUsername = usernameField.getText();
    String query = "SELECT username, password FROM adminData WHERE username='"+enteredUsername+"'";
    String username = null;
    String password = null;
    ;
    try
    {
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        String fieldWarning = "*all field are mandatory!";

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") String enteredPassword = passwordField.getText();

        usernameField.setCursor(null);
        fieldLabel.setText("");

        int userLen = enteredUsername.length();
        int passLen = enteredPassword.length();

        if (userLen != 0 && passLen != 0)
        {
            if (userLen <= 32 && passLen <= 32)
            {
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    username = rs.getString("username");
                    password = rs.getString("password");
                    if (enteredUsername.equals(username))
                    {
                        if (enteredPassword.contentEquals(password))
                        {
                            AdminDashboard frame = new AdminDashboard();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                            frame.dispose();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Missmatch");
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid User");
                        passwordField.setText("");
                        usernameField.setText("");
                        usernameField.setCursor(null);

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please enter a valid username or password! \n(Note: Only 32 char MAX)");
                passwordField.setText("");
                usernameField.setText("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fieldLabel.setText(fieldWarning);
            usernameField.setCursor(null);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database Error: " + e1);
    }
}
    });
```

Now, it will always return one record as long as your usernames are unique.

Comment: Don't do it this way: `String query = "SELECT username, password FROM adminData WHERE username='"+enteredUsername+"'";`
This code is SQL Injection affected, use `PreparedStatement` with parameters instead.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: String query = "SELECT username, password FROM adminData WHERE username=?";
...
connection.prepareStatement(query).setString(1, enteredUsername).execute()

Comment: @a.yekimov Using a prepared statement is the right way to go, but the JDBC API doesn't allow method-chaining in that way.

Comment: Don't forget to close the result set:)